# JavaScript text appears in wrong place on mobile phone, but correct place on PC webpage

Tags: javascript, android

I'm new to programming and I have been using the book "HTML5 for iOS and Android - A Beginner's Guide" (http://html5formobile.com/) to teach me the basics of creating a HTML/JavaScript web page, which is then put into a wrapper supplied with the book, to make the page function as an Android App.

The problem I am having, is that I am trying to align a piece of text to the horizontal center of the screen, purely using JavaScript. The code I have written correctly functions when viewed on my desktop PC with either Chrome or IE, however it does not function correctly once placed in the wrapper and viewed on my phone as an app or as a standalone web page viewed on my phone. Here is the small piece of code I have created to do this:

```
<script>
    instruction_text_element = document.createElement("text");
    instruction_text_node = document.createTextNode('This text should be aligned to the horizontal center of the screen.');
    instruction_text_element.appendChild(instruction_text_node);
    document.body.appendChild(instruction_text_element);
    instruction_text_element.style.position = 'absolute';
    instruction_text_element.style.left = ((screen.width / 2) - (instruction_text_element.offsetWidth / 2)) + 'px';
</script>
```

In this code, I calculate the mid point of the screen, then subtract half the width of the text element from this, to create the left position to place the text element, so that an equal amount of white space is seen on either side of the text. As mentioned, this works fine when I view it on my desktop PC with either Chrome or IE. However once it is placed in the app wrapper and viewed on either a real phone or a virtual one on my pc, or indeed when just viewed a plain web page on my phone, the text does not appear in the correct central position - it is appearing too far to the left of the screen, I'd say roughly 25% too far to the left. By this I mean the blank space on each side of the text should be 50/50 but it is showing more like 25/75.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I appreciate that my code is perhaps not the best way to go about creating and aligning text, but I am just starting out with programming and learning the basics, and so I wish to know where this PC/mobile discrepancy is arising in my code, so that I can avoid it in the future as I learn more about programming.

Many thanks for any help you can provide!

Cheers!

Updated:

As per emrys57's suggestion, I have tried the following example to see if the phone is getting confused as to its screen width:

```
<body>
<div id="div_id", style="width: 100px; background:#00CC33; text-align: center;">!</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("div_id").style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById("div_id").style.left = (window.innerWidth / 2) + 'px';
</script>

</body>
```

Again, this works fine on my desktop pc, but on my phone the little green div box is appearing too far to the left of the screen. I tried swapping screen.width out for window.innerWidth but it produces the same results. Swapping it out for window.outerWidth results in the box appearing even more too far to the left.

Does anyone know how to reliably measure the screen on a phone, or is it simply never reliable?

Cheers!

Comment: I gave up trying to measure phone screen width in px, despite using many tricks alleged to produce sensible results. I think some old Android phones have bugs in this that are never going to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried similar tricks, I found that some phone/browser combinations, particularly older ones, gave strange values for screen size. iOS seems mostly predictable, but Android wasn't. To check this, you could try placing a fixed-size little div with its left hand edge in the centre of the screen,

```
little_box.style.left = (screen.width / 2) + 'px';
```

and then measure it with a ruler. If it's not in the middle, you know the phone is confused over the screen size.

I use horizontal sizes in % to overcome this problem. All phones seem to have a good idea of what
    `width: 50%;`
means.

You could more easily align your text in the center by putting it in a div:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">!</div>
```

That "!" should appear in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've given your suggestions about the little div a go, and the phone does indeed seem to be confused about its own screen width. I have updated my original post with more details on this new test.